# Marketing cloud Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am trying to get a json object from my email template using SSJS.
 Here is my code:

```
 <script runat=server>
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

   var responseContent = HTTP.Get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/o9qvd');

   var resp = Platform.Function.parseJSON(responseContent);
   var name = resp.name;
```

here is the url I am calling: https://api.myjson.com/bins/o9qvd

and here is the error I am receiving:

> Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. Line: 5 Char: 3
>   var resp = Platform.Function.parseJSON(responseContent)

then I plan to get the name value using Ampscript inside my html as below:

> %%=v(@name)=%%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me.  Have to use [0] for the response.

```
var content = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `Platform.Function.ParseJSON()`, with a capital "P" in Parse.

Also, you only need to parse the Content property of the response object.

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
var response = HTTP.Get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/o9qvd');
Write(response.Content);
var content = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);
Write("<br>Name:" + content.name);
</script>
```

Using a cloudpage and `Write()` to see the output is often the best way to debug this type of issue.