# Patch request to update html content for an asset in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, cloudpage, content-builder

I am updating the asset in SFMC using the below mentioned API / SSJS code :

```
var assetIdToUpdate = "115271"; // Replace with the actual asset ID you want to update
var assetHTML = rest_instance_url + "/asset/v1/content/assets/" + assetIdToUpdate; 

var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
var contentType = 'application/json'
var assetHTMLresponse = HTTP.Get(assetHTML, headerNames, headerValues);
var assetHTMLcode = assetHTMLfinalresponse.views.html.content;
var assetHTMLname = assetHTMLfinalresponse.name;
var assetHTMLdescription = assetHTMLfinalresponse.description;
var assetHTMLID = assetHTMLfinalresponse.assetType.id;

var payload = {
                name: assetHTMLname,
                description: assetHTMLdescription,
                channels: {
                    email: true,
                    web: false
                },
                assetType: {
                    name: "htmlemail",
                    id: assetHTMLID
                },
                views: {
                    html: {
                        content: assetHTMLcode
                    }
                }
            };

          
            var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(assetHTML);
            req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
            req.retries = 2;
            req.continueOnError = true;
            req.contentType = "application/json"
            req.setHeader("Authorization", headerValues);
            req.method = "PATCH"; // Use PATCH method for updating existing resources
            req.postData = String(payload);

            var resp = req.send();

            var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
            
          
            Write(Stringify(resultJSON));
```

However when I publish the cloud page I am getting the below mentioned error

{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}

[image: Also I have attached the response when i stringify the payload I am assuming that the /n/n spacing problem could be one of the issue]

Comment: Does [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266474/marketing-cloud-unable-to-retrieve-security-descriptor-for-this-frame-ssjs) help?

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think your payload structure is the issue.

If you need to update other properties, retrieve a single asset using a GET on the same route -- and use that structure.

Something like this will work:

```javascript
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">

    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var assetId = 766569
    var restbase = "https://mc-zzz.rest.marketingcloudapis.com"
    var url = restbase + '/asset/v1/content/assets/' + assetId;
    var authToken = ""

    var payload = {
        "content": "<!-- whoops2 -->"
    }

    Write("<br>url: " + url)        

    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"
    req.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
    req.method = "PATCH";
    req.postData = Stringify(payload);

    try {

        var resp = req.send();
        var resultStr = String(resp.content);
        Write("<br>resultStr: " + resultStr)        
        var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(resultStr);
        Write("<br>resultJSON: " + Stringify(resultJSON))

    } catch(e) {

        Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e))

    }


</script>
```

Comment: Yes updated the same but still receiving the same error

Comment: Added an example that works.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the string form of the payload as the image. Please let me know if this is something which can cause issue

Comment: You're going to have to make the new HTML content into an escaped string that's valid in JSON.  That usually involves escaping double-quotes: `"` with `\"`.

Comment: Can you help with the function that i need to use I tried replace but it still doesn't update the HTML

Comment: You can start with `assetHTMLcode.replace(/"/g, '\\"');`